# Is the Gauss hypergeometric function $_2F_1(a,b;c,z)$ univalent in $\left|z - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, hypergeometric-functions

Consider the Gauss hypergeometric function

$$_2F_1(a,b;c,z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_nn!}z^n, \quad |z| < 1, \quad (x)_n = x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1), \quad (x)_0 = 1$$

[The Encylopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) states without reference that the analytic continuation of $_2F_1(a,b;c,z)$ on $\mathbb C \setminus [1,+\infty)$ is univalent (i.e. injective), but I believe this is wrong. If $a$ or $b$ is a non-positive integer, then $_2F_1(a,b;c,z)$ is actually a polynomial, so multiple zeros are expected and it won't be univalent. And when $a,b \notin \{0,-1,-2,...\}$, Bieberbach's theorem implies that if $_2F_1(a,b;c,z)$ is univalent on $|z| < 1$, then $\Re(a+b-c-1) \leq 1$ because of the growth of the coefficients in the above power series. Maybe some hypotheses on the parameters $a,b,c$ are missing in The Encyclopedia of Mathematics article ?

In my case, I'm interested in knowing whether $_2F_1(a,b;c,z)$ is univalent in $\left|z - \frac{1}{2} \right| < \frac{1}{2}$ when $a,b \ll -c < 0 < c$. Has this been studied already ? Sufficient conditions for univalency would be proving either that $_2F_1\left(a,b;c,\frac{1}{2}z+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is convex, starlike or almost convex on $|z| < 1$.

A toy model to study first could be $$_2F_1\left(a,a+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},z^2\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1+z)^{-2a} + (1-z)^{-2a}\right]$$
where $a \ll -1$. As a first sanity check, one observes directly that zeros can only appear when $z$ lies on the imaginary axis (hence when $z^2 \leq 0$), which we exclude here.

EDIT : I thinks this [criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative#Conditions_for_univalence) based on the Schwarzian derivative proves that the answer to my question is false.

Answer (score 4):

Conditions for univalency of $_2F_1(a,b;c,z)$ on $|z|<1$ have been established in [Univalence of Gaussian and confluent hypergeometric functions](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1990-110-02/S0002-9939-1990-1017006-8/S0002-9939-1990-1017006-8.pdf), see theorem 4. A sufficient condition is $-2\leq a<0$, $-1\leq b$, $b\neq 0$ and
$$c>\max(2+|a+b|,1-ab).$$
Further conditions are in [Univalence and Convexity Properties for Gaussian Hypergeometric Functions.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-31/issue-1/Univalence-and-Convexity-Properties-for-Gaussian-Hypergeometric-Functions/10.1216/rmjm/1008959684.full)